# How to create a complete XML message from a database query?

Tags: xml, plsql

My code below is designed to take in an xml message, iterate through it to identify the (multiple) UUID's contained within and then query a table and create an xml message with the responses.

```
  PROCEDURE test_proc (p_xml_in    IN     XMLTYPE,
                      p_xml_out    OUT XMLTYPE)
   IS
     l_xml_section                XMLTYPE;
     l_xml_body                   CLOB;
     l_xml_body_out             XMLTYPE;
     l_start_root                   VARCHAR2(20);
     l_end_root                    VARCHAR2(20); 
     v_uid_ck                       VARCHAR2(50);
     v_cd_uuid                    VARCHAR2(50);
     v_status                       VARCHAR2(50);


    BEGIN
       FOR R IN (SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(p), '//GUUID/text()') AS v_cd_uuid

                   FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(p_xml_in, '//Check/GUUIDs/GUUID'))) p)
       LOOP
        v_uid_ck := r.v_cd_uuid;

     SELECT  XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("GUUIDs",
         XMLELEMENT("GUUID", v_uid_ck)
        ,XMLELEMENT("test", t.test)
        ,XMLELEMENT("test2", t.xml_out))).extract('/*') into l_xml_section        
        from table1 t
        where v_uuid_ck = t.guuid;

         dbms_output.put_line(l_xml_section.getclobval);

         l_xml_body :='<TestResponse>' || l_xml_section || '</TestResponse>';

         l_xml_body_out := xmltype(l_xml_body);

        END LOOP;
   EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
   END;
END test_proc;
/
```

At present it is outputting the equivalent of a message per UUID, however I want one message for all UUID's i.e:

```
<UUIDs>
<UUID>123-123-1234</UUID>
<Test>Y</Test>
<Message>
    <Msg>PASS</Msg>
       <Msg_txt>more text here</Msg_txt>
</Message>
</UUIDs>
<UUIDs>
<UUID>123-123-1234</UUID>
<Test>Y</Test>
<Message>
    <Msg>PASS</Msg>
       <Msg_txt>more text here</Msg_txt>
</Message>
</UUIDs>
<UUIDs>
<UUID>123-123-1234</UUID>
<Test>Y</Test>
<Message>
    <Msg>PASS</Msg>
       <Msg_txt>more text here</Msg_txt>
</Message>
</UUIDs>
```

And I need it to look like:

```
</TestResponse>
  <UUIDs>
   <UUID>123-123-1234</UUID>
      <Test>Y</Test>
       <Message>
        <Msg>PASS</Msg>
         <Msg_txt>more text here</Msg_txt>
      </Message>
    <UUID>123-123-1234</UUID>
      <Test>Y</Test>
       <Message>
        <Msg>PASS</Msg>
         <Msg_txt>more text here</Msg_txt>
      </Message>
    <UUIDs>
</TestResponse>
```

I have tried appending a root start and end node but it says I am using the wrong type or number of arguments for || when I try anything like:

```
l_xml_body := (l_start_root||l_xml_body||l_end_root);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use APPENDCHILDXML for this. For instance, like this:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  x xmltype;
  y xmltype;
  z xmltype;
BEGIN
  x := xmltype('<UUIDs>
                <UUID>123-123-1234</UUID>
                <Test>Y</Test>
                <Message>    
                <Msg>PASS</Msg>       
                <Msg_txt>more text here</Msg_txt>
                </Message>
                </UUIDs>
                ');

  y := xmltype('<TestResponse></TestResponse>');

  --append x as child of y, below /TestResponse
  SELECT APPENDCHILDXML(y,'/TestResponse',x) INTO z FROM dual;
  --print it to the screen  
  dbms_output.put_line(z.getClobVal);

END;
```

More info on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions005.htm#SQLRF06201 and http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_appendchildxml.htm